# How to find the closest GameObject in an array with another GameObject also in that array?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game and I need to find the 2 `GameObject`s from a list closest to another `GameObject` which is also in the same list but I don't want it to return more than 2 `GameObject`s or return the `GameObject` that I'm checking against.

Here's what I want to input:

```cs
GameObject[] objects, GameObject currentObject
```

And I want it to output:

```cs
GameObject[] closestObjects, GameObject currentObject
```

I tried:

```cs
GameObject [ ] GetClosestPaths ( GameObject [ ] paths, GameObject pathToTest )
{
    GameObject[] bestTargets = new GameObject[2];
    float closestDistanceSqr = Mathf.Infinity;
    Vector3 currentPosition = pathToTest.transform.position;
    Transform[] pathTransforms = new Transform[paths.Length];

    for ( int i = 0; i < paths.Length; i++ )
    {
        pathTransforms [ i ] = paths [ i ].transform;
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < pathTransforms.Length; i++ )
    {
        if ( pathTransforms [ i ].position != currentPosition && paths [ i ] != pathToTest )
        {
            Transform potentialTarget = pathTransforms[i];
            Vector3 directionToTarget = potentialTarget.position - currentPosition;
            float dSqrToTarget = directionToTarget.sqrMagnitude;
            if ( dSqrToTarget < closestDistanceSqr )
            {
                if ( bestTargets [ 0 ] == null )
                {
                    bestTargets [ 0 ] = paths [ i ];
                }
                closestDistanceSqr = dSqrToTarget;
                if ( paths [ i ].transform.position != bestTargets [ 0 ].transform.position )
                {
                    bestTargets [ 0 ] = paths [ i ];
                }
                else
                {
                    bestTargets [ 1 ] = paths [ i ];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return bestTargets;
}
```

`paths` being the `GameObject`s, `pathToTest` being `currentObject` and `bestTargets` being `closestObjects`.

I got this on Stackoverflow and this did not work at all.
I'm hoping someone can help otherwise this goes to the infinite pile of unfinished projects.

Comment: give a try to Vector3.Distance

Comment: @oistikbal it is actually more expensive than using the `sqrMagnitude` since `Vector3.Distance` additionally needs to take the square root while for just comparing values the `sqrMagnitude` fulfills the same purpose since for positive `a < b` also means `a² < b²`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you have as input the

- GameObject pathToTest
- GameObject[] paths

And what you want is

- From `paths` return those 2 items that
- are not `pathToTest`
- are the two closest objects to `pathToTest`

So using `Linq` you could simply use

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public static class GameObjectExtensions
{
    public static GameObject[] GetClosestPaths (this GameObject pathToTest, GameObject[] paths, int maxAmount = 2)
    {
        // just cache the position once
        var positionToTest = pathToTest.transform.position;
        
        // Go through the paths
        return paths
            // Skip the "pathToTest"
            .Where(p => p != pathToTest)
            // Order them by distance to "pathToTest"
            .OrderBy(p => (p.transform.position - positionToTest).sqrMagnitude)
            // Take only up to 2 items
            .Take(maxAmount)
            // finally store the results in an array
            .ToArray();
    }

    public static GameObject[] GetClosestPaths (this GameObject[] paths, GameObject pathToTest, int maxAmount = 2)
    {
        return pathToTest.GetClosestPaths(paths, maxAmount);
    }
}
```

This will return a `GameObject[]` with **up to** 2 (by default) items (if there are enough items) that are the two closest objects to `pathToTest` without being `pathToTest` itself.

As it is an extension method now you can simply call it like

```
var closestTwoPaths = yourTargetObject.GetClosestPaths(paths);
// or also
var closestFourPaths = paths.GetClosestPaths(yourTargetObject, 4);
```

Since it can still return less then the given amount you should still always check the length of the returned array

See

- [`Enumerable.OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby)
- [`Enumerable.Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where)
- [`Enumerable.Take`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take)

Answer (score 0):

A simple check for two objects, in an array, excluding the test object, could start with an empty array, and then fill it, and shuffle the values (for ordering) as each new object in the array is tested. The resulting code could look something like this:

```cs
public static GameObject[] GetClosestPaths ( GameObject [ ] paths, GameObject pathToTest )
{
    var results = new GameObject[2];
    var resultsDistance = new float[] { float.MaxValue, float.MaxValue };
        
    for ( int i = 0; i < paths.Length; i++ )
    {
        // Unity has its mechanism to determine if two objects are equal.
        if ( paths [ i ] == pathToTest ) continue;

        // Grab the sqrDistance between the test object and the current array object.
        var d = (paths[i].transform.position - pathToTest.transform.position).sqrMagnitude;
        if ( d < resultsDistance [ 0 ] )
        {
            // Shuffle down the result if needed.
            if ( results [ 0 ] != null )
            {
                results [ 1 ] = results [ 0 ];
                resultsDistance [ 1 ] = resultsDistance [ 0 ];
            }
            results [ 0 ] = paths [ i ];
            resultsDistance [ 0 ] = d;
        }
        else if ( d < resultsDistance [ 1 ] )
        {
            results [ 1 ] = paths [ i ];
            resultsDistance [ 1 ] = d;
        }
    }

    // You can remove this debug statement once you're happy with the results.
    Debug.Log ( $"{results[0].name} - {resultsDistance[0]}\n" +
        $"{results [ 1 ].name} - {resultsDistance [ 1 ]}" );
    return results;
}
```